# Visas for US, Canada and Alaska

Tags: visas, usa

I am having difficulty finding out what visa I need to apply for and if I can even stay in the US, Canada and Alaska for over 90 days.

I will be travelling on an Australian passport and plan to fly from New Zealand into Hawaii, then LA and do a road trip making my way into Canada and possibly Alaska.

So about 2 months in the US and a few months in Canada/Alaska.

I then plan to fly home from Canada. How do I go about a visa application if my trip will be more than 90 days?

Is a VWP and ETA enough for this?

Comment: Alaska is part of the US, you know.  So you might as well say "US then Canada then the US again".

Answer (score 1):

Travelling to the USA on and ESTA allows you to stay in the US under the terms of the [VWP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/~/esta---length-of-approval):

> allows you to stay in the U.S. for 90 days or less. **If you plan to
>   stay for longer than 90 days, you must obtain a visa** at the nearest
>   U.S. Embassy or Consulate.

A Canadian [ETA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp) is for entry to Canada by air.

> visa-exempt foreign nationals who fly to or transit through Canada are
>   expected to have an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA). Exceptions
>   include U.S. citizens and travellers with a valid Canadian visa. Until
>   September 29, 2016, travellers who do not have an eTA can board their
>   flight, as long as they have appropriate travel documents, such as a
>   valid passport.
>
> **Entry requirements for other methods of travel (land, sea) have not
>   changed.**

You can stay in Canada [without a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16):

> A border services officer at the port of entry in Canada will
>   determine how long you can stay in Canada. **Most visitors are allowed a
>   six-month stay from the day they entered Canada**. If the officer
>   authorizes a stay of less than six months, they will indicate in your
>   passport the date by which you must leave Canada.

So it seems you will need to apply for a US B2 visitor visa for the US, but will not need a visa to enter Canada. However, it is up to the border service agents to ultimately decide your length of allowed stay.

Comment: The 90 days can include time in Canada, so if the OP spent two months in the continental US, then drove through Canada to visit Alaska, then exited Alaska back into Canada before the initial 90 days were up, they could avail themselves to the VWP.